# newbie lost in recursive function

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn C from a book, but there's something that's not being explained clearly enough for me.

The following code

1)counts down bottles of beer from 99 to 0 using a recursive function. 
2) Once it's out of bottles it prints "There are no more bottles on the wall" then
3) puts the bottles, one by one, in recycling

```
...       #more of same above
3 bottles of beer on wall, 3 bottles of beer 
Take one down, pass around, 2 bottls of beer 
2 bottles of beer on wall, 2 bottles of beer 
Take one down, pass around, 1 bottls of beer 
1 bottles of beer on wall, 1 bottles of beer 
Take one down, pass around, 0 bottls of beer 
There are no more bottles on the wall.
Put bottle in recycling, 1 empty bottles in bin 
Put bottle in recycling, 2 empty bottles in bin 
Put bottle in recycling, 3 empty bottles in bin 
....        #pattern continues
```

I understand how it counts down, and why it says no more bottles of beer, but I don't understand how the code (the printf)  for putting the bottle in recycling ever gets called, because it's in the else part of the conditional, and, once the number of bottles reaches 0, the function never goes back to the else part of the conditional.

Question, how does the final printf ("put bottle in recycling...")get called 99 times, and how is it able to increment the bottles one by one?

Code

```
void singTheSong(int numberOfBottles)

{

    if(numberOfBottles == 0){
        printf("There are no more bottles on the wall.\n");
    }else {
        printf("%d bottles of beer on wall, %d bottles of beer \n", numberOfBottles,numberOfBottles);
        int oneFewer = numberOfBottles - 1;
        printf("Take one down, pass around, %d bottls of beer \n", oneFewer);
        singTheSong(oneFewer);
        printf("Put bottle in recycling, %d empty bottles in bin \n", numberOfBottles);

    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    singTheSong(99);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Try putting in the `printf` statement at the very start of the function `singTheSong(...)` and also at the end of the function to enable you to understand and see what is happening...

Comment: manually working through a small case (2 or 3) might help

Comment: like the OP's username though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These three lines:

```
printf("Take one down, pass around, %d bottls of beer \n", oneFewer);
singTheSong(oneFewer);
printf("Put bottle in recycling, %d empty bottles in bin \n", numberOfBottles);
```

print these parts of the song:

```
Take one down, pass around, n - 1 bottls of beer
/* The entire song for n - 1 */
Put bottle in recycling, n empty bottles in bin
```

The final line is printed after `singTheSong` has completed executing, the stack has unrolled, and the top-level function continues executing. If you forget about the recursive call for a moment and just see the call to `singTheSong` as a black box that magically works then the behaviour of those three lines of code is no different from how any other call works.

Comment: so the final printf keeps geting added to the stack and once it's counted down from 99, then it "unrolls" i.e. the last printfs get called on a last in first out basis, which accounts for the recycling from 1 to 99?

Answer (score 0):

This might help.  Think of substituting the first call for the actual body of the function:

```
void singTheSong(int numberOfBottles)

{

    if(numberOfBottles == 0){
        printf("There are no more bottles on the wall.\n");
    }else {
        printf("%d bottles of beer on wall, %d bottles of beer \n", numberOfBottles,numberOfBottles);
        int oneFewer = numberOfBottles - 1;
        printf("Take one down, pass around, %d bottls of beer \n", oneFewer);
        singTheSong(oneFewer);
        printf("Put bottle in recycling, %d empty bottles in bin \n", numberOfBottles);

    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int numberOfBottles=99;

    if(numberOfBottles == 0){
        printf("There are no more bottles on the wall.\n");
    }else {
        printf("%d bottles of beer on wall, %d bottles of beer \n", numberOfBottles,numberOfBottles);
        int oneFewer = numberOfBottles - 1;
        printf("Take one down, pass around, %d bottls of beer \n", oneFewer);
        singTheSong(oneFewer);
        printf("Put bottle in recycling, %d empty bottles in bin \n", numberOfBottles);

    }
    return 0; 
}
```

On the first call, when numberOfBottles==99, The `if (numberOfBottles == 0)` will fail, and only the else part will be executed.  It will print two lines, call singTheSong(98), and then print the line about recycling.

Imagine continuing to do substitutions like this, and you may see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

When using recursion, there are three phases:
 1. The termination condition (in this case "no bottles of beer" (sad situation! - but not so bad if you started with 99, I suppose). Without this, you get infinite recursion, which isn't a good thing!
 2. The recursive call. 
 3. What you do after the recursive steps so far has finished.

So, like a true drinking party, no one cleans up until the party has finished and there are no more beer. Instead, we go fetch another bottle from the wall, sing a bit, pass the bottle around, and when that bottle is finished, we get another from the wall, sing, drink, fetch bottle, sing, etc, etc. Once ALL the bottles are finished (0 bootles), we tidy up by returning (no more singing and drinking, closing time, etc). And of course, the "return" from a recursive call starts at the deepest call level (with the LAST bottle of beer = 1 bottle 'left'), then goes back down a level (2 bottles), then down another level (3 bottles) and so on.

Sometimes people talk about "tail recursion", and that's when the FINAL step of the recursion is to call the function itself.

Comment: so the final printf in SingSong doesn't get called until there are 0 bottles left, i.e. they keep piling up and then get called in a reverse order for the recycling? starting at 1? Last in first out?

Comment: Jup, exactly - just like in the drinking lots in a movie or TV show or some such - you see the bottles just filling the entire table.